# Push error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, git-push

Не могу запушить изменения ни в master, ни в другие branches. **Pull работает.**

В чем может быть причина?

```
$ git push origin  module1-patch1
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 2.10 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 23 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
To https://github.com/username/repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] module1-patch1 -> module1-patch1 (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/repository.git'`
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас нет прав на изменение репозитория.

Comment: как их вернуть?

Comment: а они у вас были? вы когда-нибудь делали push в этот репозиторий?

Comment: Были вчера и сегодня, делал пуш и пул.

Comment: Наверное, будет проще создать новый удалённый репо, чем искать причину?

Comment: @Millionaire, вы владеете репозиторием? Если нет, значит вас убрали из *collaborators*.

Comment: Да. Это форк. Только с ним работаю, без пулриквеста.

Comment: Я могу сам себя убрать из collaborators, после чего pull разрешен, а push - нет?

Comment: @Millionaire, наверное. Кстати, у вас какая ОС (на MacOS [была похожая проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40069344/2553424))? И да, попробуйте заменить HTTPS-версию remote на SSH-версию (плюс сгенерируйте ключ и добавьте его в настройки профиля на Гитхабе).

Comment: @Millionaire если проект публичный, то pull всегда разрешен. возможно вы не залогинены. добавьте результат `git remote -v` в вопрос.

Comment: Win7. <br> '[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
  useHttpPath = true' - не помогло<br>

Comment: @Millionaire добавьте информацию в вопрос

Comment: Win7. [credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
  useHttpPath = true - не помогло; SHH не помогло. Про ключ не понял, Deploy keys что ли?; Я залогинен. P.S.: Я использую 2 пользователя для git, один --global user, второй для конкретного репо. Хотел сам с собой попрактиковать пулриквест. Глобальный пользователь пушит норм, а этот через пару длей сломался). Надеюсь мне не понадобиться в будущем 2 пользователя для git.

Comment: @Millionaire Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.